# WIndows/iPython: my arrow keys are not scrolling through command history (python 3.6.5)

Tags: ipython

I am trying to use iPython 6.4.0 on my gitbash terminal (using python 3.6.5). The problem I am having is that the arrow keys don't seem to be working properly in iPython. When I press the up arrow key, it does not go through past commands; it instead moves up a line in the terminal. This is the same with the other arrow keys, where they just move through the terminal lines instead of the ^[[(letter) output. Anyone know of a way to fix this?

I'm sorry if this question is not very clear, I am very new to python.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this.

The solution is to:

```
winpty ipython
```

As you need to use winpty to get things like readline working in programs.